# Range of Bytes32

Tags: solidity, evm, bytes32

What is the unsigned range of a bytes32 type in Solidity?

I'm wondering the total number of unique expressible combinations. I'm assuming it is `2^8^32`.

Comment: You are correct bytes32 have 32 bytes you have 256^32 = (2^8)^32 possible combinations.

Comment: @Ismael Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct `bytes32` has 32 bytes, each byte has 256 combination then you will have `256×256×..{32 veces}..×256 = 256^32 = (2^8)^32` possible combinations total.